# Using XPath In Cycle For

Tags: vba, xpath

I'm trying to solve one simple problem that i can't understand how i could solve in excel vba.

I have one cycle for and a Xpath with 24 elements and i want to get text from each element, but when i use xpath shows me that i put the wrong xpath. I understand that i put i inside the string of xpath and that get me wrong. I try different approach like using

`Name.Add findApp.FindElementByXPath("(//span[@class='offer-item-title'])["&"i]").Text`
but nothing seems work. Can someone help me how i could solve this? Thank you so much :)

**Code:**

```
for i=0 to 23

Name.Add findApp.FindElementByXPath("(//span[@class='offer-item-title'])[i]").Text

Next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath doesn't know that `i` is the name of a VB variable, it thinks it is the name of an element in your source document.

You can construct an expression like this:

`FindElementByXPath("(//span[@class='offer-item-title'])[" & i & "]")`

Or better, but I don't know if VBA offers the capability, is to pass a parameter into the XPath expression -- ideally you only want to compile the XPath expression once, rather than repeating the compilation 23 times, because compiling it typically takes 100 times longer than executing it.

But for this particular example, it would be better to construct an expression that reads everything you want in one go, rather than making 24 separate calls. Incidentally, XPath indexing starts at one, so the call with i=0 will select nothing. Given that this is XPath 1.0, you can do

```
//span[@class='offer-item-title'])[position() < 24]
```

Comment: Thanks @QHarr I've improved my answer to take your comments into account.